# connect call from local number to termination provider

Tags: sip, voip, termination, telecommunication

We are a telecom company that allow our clients to call from a mobile application or their landline to friend or family around the globe...

Our system works like these application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebtel.android

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.talkhome

We have three kind of calls:

1) - Direct call: A customer calls a virtual phone number with some dtmf code. This call is then transfered to a sip or voip call. The sip or voip then call the customer destination based on this dtmf code.

2) - Callback: A customer makes a web request via http connection or by  sending  an SMS  to our platform. The sms contains some secret key, the destination number and some additional information. Base on these informations we will make request to our provider to make a call to the destination and our customer.

3) - Voip call: The client call through voip channel with his account.

We have already an termination voip provider. I'm looking for an company or a solution that can help me to connect from the DID numbers to the termination voip provider.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please clarify what's the missing part here?
2. Do You have SIP softswitch already? If yes let me know maybe i can help You in configuration to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, we didn't have the softswitch yet. I'm looking for a softswitch with api so i can contact to the softswitch in order to create an account, make a call through, make a callback...

Comment: I am working for a company which offer a softswitch which could satisfy Your needs. I feel pointy 1 you mean calling card business (call through Access number, then enter Pin code to recognize Your account and enter destination number by dtmf which ja reached by VoIP/sip protocol using other VoIP Provident gateways) Let me know if you interessed i will update my profile do You can Contact me directly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Please contact me by mp. Thanks

Comment: Could You please clarify how to contact with You? I was on Your profile and coudn't find any e-mail address or skype id.

Comment: Please look at my profile, i leaved contact to my company e-mail. I am waiting for Your response.